# How to call multiple line in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, amazon-ec2

I WANT TO CALL MULTIPLE LINE IN THE BATCH FILE HOW CAN I DO THAT .

(THIS IS THE LINE WHAT I WANT TO CALL)

```
call ec2-describe-spot-price-history -H --instance-type t1.micro --start-time 2014-05-29T16:00:00 --end-time 2014-05-29T017:00:00 --availability-zone us-east-1a >> out.txt

call ec2-describe-spot-price-history -H --instance-type t1.micro --start-time 2014-05-29T16:00:00 --end-time 2014-05-29T017:00:00 --availability-zone us-east-1b  >> out.txt
```

HOW CAN I CALL THESE 2 LINE TOGETHER IN A BATCH FILE

THIS IS BATCH FILE WHAT IS RITE NOW

```
@echo on

echo "file init

call ec2-describe-spot-price-history -H --instance-type t1.micro --start-time 2014-05-29T16:00:00 --end-time 2014-05-29T017:00:00 --availability-zone us-east-1a  >> out.txt

echo "file written"

FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%i in (out.txt) do echo %%i

echo "file done"

pause
```

OUT PUT OF THE BATCH FILE :

```
Type    Price   Timestamp   InstanceType    ProductDescription  AvailabilityZone
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE   0.006100    2014-05-29T09:29:08+0530    t1.micro    Windows us-east-1b
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE   0.006100    2014-05-29T04:52:09+0530    t1.micro    SUSE Linux  us-east-1b
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE   0.003100    2014-05-29T04:52:08+0530    t1.micro    Linux/UNIX  us-east-1b
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure this is what you are asking, give it a try.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    echo file init

    set "filter="
    (   for %%a in ( us-east-1a us-east-1b ) do (
            call ec2-describe-spot-price-history -H ^
                    --instance-type t1.micro ^
                    --start-time 2014-05-29T16:00:00 ^
                    --end-time 2014-05-29T017:00:00 ^
                    --availability-zone %%a | findstr /r /c:".*!filter!"
            if not defined filter set "filter=t1.micro"
        )
    ) > out.txt

    echo "file written"

    FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%i in (out.txt) do echo %%i

    echo "file done"

    pause
```

Comment: error :                                                                    Client.InvalidParameterValue: Invalid availability zone: [%a]

Comment: @user323041, the `%%a` is the replaceable parameter of the `for` loop and should be replaced with one of the values in the `in (` set. `%a` should never reach the `ec2-....` call. It is case sensitive, so ensure you don't have both `%%a` and `%%A`